# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on adding audio Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to add some audio when a button is pressed and the code I use doesnt have any error until I run then I get the 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' in the out put this line of code:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:sound, withExtension: "mp3")!
```

This is my entire code just for reference:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


let soundFilenames = ["60gs", "check", "dada", "danceforme", "eat", "gods", "irelandbaby", "ko'd", "lefthand", "littlewerp", "nocalls", "precision", "sundaymorning", "surprise", "whothefuckisthatguy", "youlldonothing"]

var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for sound in soundFilenames {

        do {

            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:sound, withExtension: "mp3")!
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

            audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
        }
        catch {

            audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())

        }
    }



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.play()

}
```

}

Comment: Print `sound`, and check that you correclty have it in your bundle app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is self-describing: `url(forResource: withExtension:)` returned nil and force-unwrapping it with `!` causes your crash.

To fix this crash re-check that:

- all files were added to the project
- file names are written right in the code

Comment: And be sure they are assigned to the target. Generally it's a bad idea to force unwrap things.

Comment: @Matz is right: prefer using **if let** to get rid of force-unwrapping.

Comment: @Matz Generally it is. But in this particular case it reveals a design error.

Answer (score 1):

If the file names are not needed later there is a more reliable way to get all mp3 files in the resources folder

```
let audioURLs = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "mp3", subdirectory: nil)!
for url in audioURLs {
    do {
        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
    }
    catch {
        audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
    }
}
```

or - inspired by Alexander's comment – shortly

```
let audioURLs = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "mp3", subdirectory: nil)!
audioPlayers = audioURLs.flatMap{ try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: $0) }
```

Comment: `let audioPlayers = audioURLs.flatMap{ do { return try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: $0) } catch { return AVAudioPlayer() } }`

Comment: @Alexander I would even omit the `do - catch` block (`try? AVAudioPlayer`) because empty players are not meaningful in practice. But I didn't want to confuse the OP too much ;-)